# Escape velocity work done problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, orbital-motion, escape-velocity

We derive the formula of escape velocity by using conservation of mechanical energy, where we consider that work done by external force is neglected. But to provide the velocity to send an object to infinite distance from gravitational pull of Earth, don't we have to apply an external force?

Answer (score 3):

> to provide velocity to send to infinite distance from gravitational pull of earth so for that we have to apply external force

This is called an “initial velocity”. The problem begins at the “initial time”, after the object is already traveling at the initial velocity. We don’t care how it got the initial velocity, only what comes after the initial time.

During our analysis, there is no external force after the initial time. What happened before the initial time is not important to the analysis afterwards.

Comment: Ok but the work energy theorem says net work done = change in KE ,Net work done = work done by external force + conservative force ..and idea of conservation of energy comes from work energy theorem itself so how that initial KE + PE =Final KE +PE . Because to satisfy conservation of energy the internal conservative force should act which is in this case is gravity that's fine but what about external force ..or can we provide velocity without external force .so could you please explain that

Comment: There is no external force from the initial time to the final time. What happened outside of that time is irrelevant. It doesn’t matter how you got the initial velocity. It doesn’t matter if the initial velocity was provided by internal forces, external forces, or if the object was created already moving at that velocity. It is irrelevant.

Comment: Tell me one thing for work done force should be applied throughout the displacement or just you hit the ball and it travels some distance i.e just at the initial time and covers some distance

Comment: So if external force acts......... Ok I consider we don't consider anything before initial velocity but tell me that concept with work energy theorem please.. really appreciate